# Aggregate list values in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

Starting with a list of objects containing two parameters notional and currency, how can I aggregate the total notional per currency?

Given:

```
case class Trade(name: String, amount: Int, currency: String)

val trades = List(
  Trade("T150310", 10000000, "GBP"),
  Trade("T150311", 10000000, "JPY"),
  Trade("T150312", 10000000, "USD"),
  Trade("T150313", 100, "JPY"),
  Trade("T150314", 1000, "GBP"),
  Trade("T150315", 10000, "USD")
)
```

How can I get:

```
Map(JPY -> 10000100, USD -> 10010000, GBP -> 10001000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a simple group-by operation (actually a `Groupable` `trait` with an implicit conversion from an `Iterable`) which would allow you to group your trades by their `currency`:

```
trait Groupable[V] extends Iterable[V] {
  def groupBy(f: V => K): MultiMap[K, V] = {
    val m = new mutable.HashMap[K, Set[V]] with mutable.MultiMap[K, V]
    foreach { v => m add (f(v), v) } //add is defined in MultiMap
    m
  }
}
implicit def it2groupable(it: Iterable[V]): Groupable[V] = new Groupable[V] {
  def elements = it.elements
}
```

So `Groupable` is simply providing a way to extract a *key* from each item in an `Iterable` and then grouping all such items which have the same key. So, in your case:

```
//mm is a MultiMap[Currency, Trade]
val mm = trades groupBy { _.currency }
```

You can now do a quite simple `mapElements` (`mm` is a `Map`) and a `foldLeft` (or `/:` - well worth understanding the `foldLeft` operator as it enables extremely concise aggregations over collections) to get the sum:

```
val sums: Map[Currency, Int] = mm mapElements { ts => 
    (0 /: ts) { (sum,t) => sum + t.notional } 
}
```

Apologies if I've made some mistakes in that last line. `ts` are the values of `mm`, which are  (of course) `Iterable[Trade]`.

Answer (score 17):

If you use trunk the machinery is already there.  groupBy is defined on Traversable and sum can be applied directly to the list, you don't have to write a fold.

```
scala> trades groupBy (_.currency) map { case (k,v) => k -> (v map (_.amount) sum) }
res1: Iterable[(String, Int)] = List((GBP,10001000), (JPY,10000100), (USD,10010000))
```

Comment: And can you explain where the sum function is coming from?

Comment: Yes, what is trunk now is what 2.8 will be.  The sum method is defined on NumericTraversableOps - which is not a class you need to know anything about - but it basically adds methods to Traversable by way of implicit based on the presence of a Numeric[T], which itself defines "add" so sum can be generically defined.

Comment: The last comment is a bit out of date, as `sum` is now defined on ` TraversableTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, most collections are provided with the [groupMapReduce](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]) method which is (as its name suggests) an equivalent (more efficient) of a `groupBy` followed by `mapValues` and a reduce step:

```
trades.groupMapReduce(_.currency)(_.amount)(_ + _)
// immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(JPY -> 10000100, USD -> 10010000, GBP -> 10001000)
```

This:

- `group`s elements based on their currency (group part of **group**MapReduce)
- `map`s grouped values to their amount (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
- `reduce`s values (`_ + _`) by summing them (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**).

This is an equivalent version [performed in one pass](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L604) through the List of:

```
trades.groupBy(_.currency).mapValues(_.map(_.amount).reduce(_+_))
```